# new error: Actual and formal argument lists differ in length

Tags: java

Trying to finish an assignment for my first year comp class. So far everything's been okay, but I can't figure this one error out. I was wondering if anyone could help out here? I tried changing my variables to doubles and obviously it didnt work.

```js
import java.util.Scanner;
public class CellPhoneProgram {
  public static Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
  //declare x and y coordinates for each city
  public static double xa = 100, xb = 100, xc = 340, xd = 230, ya = 360, yb = 360, yc = 250, yd = 140;

  public static int getRange(int city) {
    int range = 0;
    System.out.println("What is the maximum distance (in km) from the center of City " + city + " that you may travel without losing service?");
    range = keyboard.nextInt();
    return range;
  }

   /* ERROR OCCURS HERE */
  public static double distance(double xf, double xi, double yf, double yi) {
    double distance = 0;
    distance = Math.sqrt((Math.pow(xf - xi)) - (Math.pow(yf - xi)));
    return distance;
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    int city1, city2, city3, city4;
    double distance1, distance2, distance3;

    System.out.println("Welcome to the Cell Phone Service Program, where you enter the range of service from four cities," +
      " and we calculate whether or not you lose service.");
    //get range from function
    city1 = getRange(1);
    city2 = getRange(2);
    city3 = getRange(3);
    city4 = getRange(4);

    System.out.println(city3);

    //calculate distances from cities
    distance1 = distance(xb, xa, yb, ya);
    distance2 = distance(xc, xb, yc, yb);
    distance1 = distance(xd, xc, yd, yc);

    System.out.println(distance1);
  }
}
```

here's a look at the error:

```js
File: C:\Users\Katie\Documents\Homework\CellPhoneProgram.java  [line: 16]
Error: method pow in class java.lang.Math cannot be applied to given types;
  required: double,double
  found: double
  reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length
File: C:\Users\Katie\Documents\Homework\CellPhoneProgram.java  [line: 16]
Error: method pow in class java.lang.Math cannot be applied to given types;
  required: double,double
  found: double
  reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length
```

This code is definitely still in progress, sorry about the messiness and incomplete code and all that.

Answer (score 0):

Math.pow() requires two arguments not one. I am guessing you want to raise to the second power so the second argument should be 2.

```
Math.sqrt((Math.pow(xf - xi,2)) - (Math.pow(yf - xi,2)));
```

See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#pow%28double,%20double%29